# How to check listview item's step by step

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I'm pretty beginner,so take me easy. I have two listview parallel , and i want when i click on item from this listview's to be checked. I tried to make but i don't know where i go wrong, and if you can explain step by step if it's not correct what i understand how to make this listview's with checkmark.

Here onclick() i know when it's pressed and i get the message CHECK or UNCHECK, but when i get the view from listViewSelectFile CheckedTextView item = (CheckedTextView ) view; he give me this error : android.widgetlinearlayout cannot be cast to android.widget.checkedtextview .Any ideea how to fix this ?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterFile = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_view_rows, R.id.textView1, mImageFilenames);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterStudent = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, R.layout.list_view_rows, R.id.textView1, Username_s);
    listViewSelectFile.setAdapter(adapterFile);
    listViewSelectStudent.setAdapter(adapterStudent);

    listViewSelectFile
            .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                    try {
                        LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) view;
                        CheckedTextView CheckedTextView = (CheckedTextView)item.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                        if (!item.isActivated()) {
                            String state = mImageFilenames[position]
                                    .toString();
                            // if(listViewSelectFile.isActivated())
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Unclicked on : " + state,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                          
                            listViewSelectFile.setItemChecked(position,
                                    false);                                 
                            CheckedTextView.setChecked(false);
                        } else {
                            String state = mImageFilenames[position]
                                    .toString();
                            // if(listViewSelectFile.isActivated())
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Clicked on : " + state,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            listViewSelectFile.setItemChecked(position,
                                    true);
                             CheckedTextView.setChecked(true);

                            }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            });
    listViewSelectStudent
            .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    try{
                    String state = Username_s[position].toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Clicked on : " + state, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                }

            });
```

**and my xml, 2 parallel listview's :**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listviewSelectStudents"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
            >
        </ListView>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listviewSelectFiles"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">
        </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

list_view_rows.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <CheckedTextView  
      android:id="@+id/textView1" 
      android:paddingLeft="20dip" 
      android:paddingRight="20dip" 
      android:paddingTop="10dip"
      android:paddingBottom="10dip" 
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"  
      android:gravity="center_vertical"  
      android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" 
      android:onClick="toggle" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The code from top it's WORK , so who wanna an example with 2 listview parralel + checktext this is grea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying your `R.layout.list_view_rows` code, but I bet you are using a TextView instead of a CheckedTextView. You need a CheckedTextView to have the CheckBoxes added.

Comment: I modified to CheckedTextView but nothing changed , i don't see checkboxes added

Comment: You definetely need it, so there is another error somewhere else. I will test your code in a hour and catch it (I am too busy now, sorry).

Comment: I replace CheckedTextView with radio button , and work's .Do you have any idee why with checkedtextview doesn't work ? and how can i check listview[position].itschecked () ? . Thank you !

Comment: On the other hand, in your main layout you just need a single LinearLayout and two ListViews with width=0dip, height=match_parent, weight=1 inside it (don't use 'fill_parent' anymore, it's deprecated).

Comment: When you can help me to check and uncheck this radio's buttons, or with checked text view . Thank you !

Comment: I tried and with CheckedTextView ...when i get the view from listViewSelectFile         CheckedTextView item = (CheckedTextView ) view;  he give me this error : android.widgetlinearlayout cannot be cast to android.widget.checkedtextview

Comment: The problem is when i checked a item from this listview !!! Example : If i select first item from listview , next item's until i move the scroll from listview are unchecked. If on one page they can be maxim 9 item's to see (first item is check next 8 is unchecked) and the 10 item is checked then next 8 item's are unchecked then the item 19 is checked and so far one. I tested and with the phone horizontal and it's the same problem. Do you have any ideea ? I think the problem appear is when i move the scroll next item's(CheckTextView) he give the id 0

Comment: , and he multiply my CheckTextViewid. How can i solve this ? Any example ? Thank you !!!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698593/multiple-checks-on-listview-are-multiplied-checks-on-listview-are-multiplied